# Does the volume of matrices satisfy the triangle inequalilty?

Tags: linear-algebra

As we know that the volume of a matrix $X$ is defined as $\sqrt{\det(X^TX)}$, if we consider the volume spanned by two matrices $X$ and $Y$, with $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times d},d<N,\dim(X)=\dim(Y)=d$, then the volume of $[X,Y]$ is $\sqrt{\det([X,Y]^T[X,Y])}$.
My question is, Does this volume $vol([X,Y])=\sqrt{\det([X,Y]^T[X,Y])}$ satisfy the triangle inequality? In another word, if we have $X,Y,Z \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times d}, \dim(X)=\dim(Y)=\dim(Z)=d$, will this relationship
$vol([X,Y]) \leq vol([X,Z] + vol([Z,Y])$
hold? If so, under what condition will the equality hold?